# Brand new Trek X-Caliber 7 - RockShox 30 Silver lockout not working

Tags: fork, suspension, front

I just bought a brand new bike fitted with RockShox 30 Silver front forks and took it for a ride on disused railway gravel cycle track. The lockout dial does not seem to do anything. This is my first time with suspension forks so no idea what to expect.

Comment: If its brand new from a shop - take it back under warranty.  Could be faulty, or coul dbe a lack of user training.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't do anything? Lockout basically makes the suspension act as if its rigid (i.e. the fork won't bounce up and down).

Comment: Thanks ... took it back to the shop and now fixed (and trained) ... :-)